# Android: DrawText above Rectangle objects

Tags: android, canvas, path, drawtext

I have a list of path objects which are rectangles stored in an `array-list`. I want to draw Text on the bottom of every path object.

I have tried but the text only appears on one path object. Also, if i want to give a index to the rectangle name how do i go about it?

My codes are as follows:

```
    for (RectF rec : rects) {
        for(String name : nameArr){
        if (rec.height() != 50 ) {
            canvas.drawOval(rec, paintColor);
            canvas.drawText(name, x, y, paint);

        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(rec, paintColor);
            canvas.drawText(name,x,y, paint);
        }
```

here X and Y are touch coordinates.

I have used the above code but the name only appear one at a time. For example for the first rectangle i have added, the name appears successfully but when i added the second rectangle, the name from the first rectangle jumped to second rectangle. I guess this got to do with the touch coordinates since it is always changing. And how do i draw it below the rectangles?

any way i can do to ensure the name will always remain fix below the rectangle?

here's the output i want to achieve.

http://postimg.org/image/9qsu5ltan/

Comment: see Canvas.drawTextOnPath

Comment: @pskink oh, this looks good but this dont work for rect but for path right? cos currently using a rectf arraylist.

Comment: your question says "DrawText above path objects" so i suggested drawTextOnPath

Comment: @pskink i'm sorry! didn't phrase the question in a correct manner. i have made changes to my question.